# How to store a variable in android

Tags: android, variables, android-spinner

I want to store a variable in my project. In fact, I want the user to choose an option via a drop down list, and store the value of this variable to be able to still use it in my other activities

My spinner code :

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

  private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
  private Button btnSubmit;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
  }

  // add items into spinner dynamically
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

  public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }

  // get the selected dropdown list value
  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: There are several ways to storage like SharedPreference, Database, etc..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SharedPreferences to store information for future use in your App.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

There are of course several other ways to solve it but this one is pretty straight forward.

More information about storage can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

You can make this in two ways:

First method allows you to keep the data only while the application is running, the other method will keep the data even if the application is closed.

1. Create a class GlobalData

   ```
   public enum GlobalData {

       Data;

       private boolean isBooleanVal= false;


       public boolean isBooleanVal() {
        return isBooleanVal;
       }

        public void setBooleanVal(boolean isQuizStartedAgain) {
          this.isQuizStartedAgain = isBooleanVal;
       }
   }
   ```

And call it in other class:

```
   GlobalData.Data.setBooleanVal(true);
```

OR

```
   GlobalData.Data.isBooleanVal();
```

2. Using SharedPreferences

   ```
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(value,value);
    editor.commit();
   ```

[Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)